# I want to get the sum total of one whole field(number type) in another field of the same table

Tags: ms-access-2013

For example, in the table below I want to get the total(sum of all the entries) of Sum_Record field in Total_record field of same table i.e 75 [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmBei.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use a form and set this to *DataSheetView*.

Then you can add the Totals line.